# NLog logger doesn't log to the configured logfile in release build

Tags: c#, nlog

I have the configuration file set up

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    </configSections>
    <nlog autoReload="true">
        <targets>
            <target name="file" type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log/${shortdate}.log" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss.fff}|${message}"/>
            <target name="file_webs" type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log/${shortdate}_webs.log" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss.fff}|${message}"/>
        </targets>
        <rules>
            <logger name="WebSocket.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file_webs" final="true"/>
            <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="file" />
        </rules>
    </nlog>
</configuration>
```

The logger is loaded in each class like this:

```cs
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

The logging is directed to the correct file as long as I don't run the build version. Then all logging is done in the default log file.
What could be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following:

- Is the correct config file placed in the output directory of the release. Maybe there is a different version of your config file there or it is missing.
- Are there other things running after your build? Like a tool to obfuscate the source code? If so, this might mess up the class name in your build, the config the can not redirect to the right output. In that case, explicitly load the logger for your class this way:

```cs
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("WebSocket.*");
```

Comment: I check the config file in the output directory. That was fine. But indeed, there is a kind of obfuscater running after the release build. Not sure what it does. I changed my code as you suggested. Now the logging is always in the correct file. This workaround has solved the problem. Thanks!